# Laravel factory startup error Array to string conversion

Tags: php, laravel, factory, laravel-factory

In my Laravel project I am using the Astrotomic Laravel Translatable package. I want to create a factory to generate random data.My factory code

```
public function definition(): array
{
    $locales = ['uk', 'ru'];

    $translations = collect($locales)->mapWithKeys(function($locale) {
        return [
            $locale => [
                'slug' => fake()->unique()->randomNumber(4) . '-' . fake()->slug(3),
                'name' => fake()->unique()->name(),
                'description' => fake()->text(),
                'education' => fake()->text(),
            ]
        ];
    })->toArray();

    return array_merge([
        'city_id' => City::get()->random()->id,
        'degree' => fake()->numberBetween(1, 2),
        'qualification' => fake()->numberBetween(1, 3),
        'start_year' => fake()->year(),
        'viewed' => fake()->numberBetween(50, 5500),
        'status' => true,
        'image' => fake()->imageUrl(250, 250),
        'sort_order' => fake()->numberBetween(0, 10),
        'created_at' => fake()->dateTimeBetween('-4 week', '-3 week'),
        'updated_at' => fake()->dateTimeBetween('-2 week', '-1 week'),
    ], $translations);
}
```

I get an error when starting the factory, please help me(

```
   ErrorException

  Array to string conversion

  at vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Support\Str.php:964
    960▕
    961▕         $result = array_shift($segments);
    962▕
    963▕         foreach ($segments as $segment) {
  ➜ 964▕             $result .= (array_shift($replace) ?? $search).$segment;
    965▕         }
    966▕
    967▕         return $result;
    968▕     }

  1   vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Support\Str.php:964
      Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\HandleExceptions::Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\{closure}()

  2   vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\QueryException.php:67
      Illuminate\Support\Str::replaceArray()
```

Comment: Is that full error stack?

Comment: yes(( i tried even writing all in one array without array_merge and still same error

Comment: hmm.. have you set up your locales in the config of the package, as a sanity check that your array is well formed what does dd(); the array you return in the factory prints?

Comment: Use `$this->faker->` instead of `fake()->`

Comment: I tried $this->faker and instead of locales I just wrote any letters and numbers so as not to depend on the package, still the same error